# Swagger Duplication

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm using Swagger to document an API.

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("v1/[controller]/[action]")]

    [Route("fullrecord/{provider}/{identifier}")]
    public class FullRecord : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetRecordMethod(string provider, string identifier)
        {
```

Swagger then reports both the route, and the method name.

FullRecord

GET
​/v1​/FullRecord​/GetRecordMethod
GET
​/v1​/fullrecord​/{provider}​/{identifier}

Comment: What library do you use - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, something else?

Comment: services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",

Comment: But isnt that logical, because you have 2 routes, one with params and one without with action name in route. i think you intended to place the second route above the method not the class

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you.